# Wordpress/PHP create a static copy of the page

Tags: php, wget, static-pages

I need to make a static page from the dynamic one with all assets downloaded and all the links converted to local ones and download it in some tmp folder. Like when you press Ctrl+S in a browser. I tried using `wget` with `shell_exec`:

```
shell_exec("wget -E -H -k -p http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/  2>&1");
```

The problem is that it works perfectly when I run it from console, but when I use `shell_exec`, I get an error

> Permission denied youmightnotneedjquery.com/index.html: No such file
>   or directory Cannot write to 'youmightnotneedjquery.com/index.html'
>   (No such file or directory).

As I understand, there is some problem with permissions, I tried to create a seperate directory
with some high permissions and www-data as owner and specify it in the command using -O flag, but I get an error that I can't use -k and -O flags at the same time. So I hope to solve that issue with permission, but I still have to specify the destination folder somehow. Or maybe there's a php solution without wget that I can use, as it seems not quite hard but a lot of work to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helped using -P flag and creating a folder with owned www-data

```
shell_exec("wget -E -H -k -p http://mysite.local/ -P some-temp-folder 2>&1")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like 
`shell_exec("cd some_nice_dir && wget ...")`

You may also want to read up on `man wget` as it has a lot to say about interferences between `-O` and several of the other options you specify.